# Split a row with multiple array values into separate rows

Tags: excel

The first two columns in each row identify a Vendor Name and Email. The remaining columns are Subject and the score listed below.

Original Table
[image: Original Table]

I need to create a new row for each Vendor and Email by subject and score that is not blank.

[image: Outcome]

UPDATE: I was able to expand the number of rows so that if the vendor has completed 3 subjects then the vendor now has three rows. I used [these instructions](https://www.excel-university.com/insert-x-rows-to-expand-table/) which worked perfectly.
I also created the two columns "Subject" and "Score".

TODO:  Now I am trying to swing the column names(Subjects) into the proper row if there is a value. After that, I should be able to do a vlookup to grab the Score.

Comment: I made some progress seen in the "Update"...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Power Query transformation.  There is no simple formula, and the VBA code is not worth the trouble when you have a better option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).